# On Horizon Install - Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: horizon

I am trying to install `Horizon`. I am not using the self signed certificates that SIF installs. I am using my own cert (Possible source of problem?). Horizon install fails with Could not create `SSL/TLS secure channel`.:

```
Invoke-InstallPackageTask : Exception calling "InstallZipPackage" with "2" argument(s):
"System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. --->
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved'        event. ---> 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. --->
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)           at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentStore.Save(SegmentDefinition    segmentDefinition)
at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.DeploySegmentDefinitionProcessor.DeploySegment(SegmentDefinition  segmentDefinition)
at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.DeploySegmentDefinitionProcessor.DeploySegment(Item segmentItem)     at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.Events.SegmentDeployedEventHandler.OnItemSaved(Object sender,     EventArgs args)
at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)        at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args)
at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args)
at (Object , Object )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item)
at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)
at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)
at Sitecore.Data.DataManager.SetWorkflowInfo(Item item, WorkflowInfo info)
at Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.Workflow.SetStateID(Item item, String stateID, StringDictionary commentFields, String  workflowID)
at Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.Workflow.PerformTransition(Item commandItem, Item item, ID stateId, StringDictionary   commentFields)
at Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.Workflow.CommandActionsComplete(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at PackageInstaller.InstallZipPackage(String packagePath, String token)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---"
At 
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.2.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:25    +                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-InstallPackageTask], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SoapException,Invoke-InstallPackageTask
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue, then I checked this blog https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/10/All-about-xConnect-Security/ and `System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.` paragraph.

To add permission to the certificate, please follow the below steps:

1. Type `mmc` on run
2. Go to `File` and click on `Add/Remove Snap-in`
3. Double click on certificate and select `Computer account`
4. Click on `Finish`
5. Now select `Personal->Certificate`

[image]

1. In the right hand side, select your client certificate
2. Right-click on a certificate and select `All Tasks` then `Manage Private Keys`
3. Click on 'Add' and type `IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPoolsName`, the location should be `Local Computer` and grant a `Read` permission.

If this does not resolve your issue then go to `Event Viewer` and check which account is failing, in my case, it was 'Network Service'

[image]

Then I have added 'Network Service' permission as well and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, this was an xconnect issue, not Horizon. To solve, I have to give the Sitecore App Pool permission to my cert.

Open Cert manager - In windows, click start button and type 'cert' - open the 'Manage Computer Certificates' tool

Drill down to Personal/certiciates

[image]

Find your certificate on the right
Right click on you certificate and choose All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys

This will give you a typical Windows Security dialog. Add the app pool that needs access to the certificate. In my case I added Sitecore and XConnect. I gave them full control

Comment: Can you add steps on how to add permissions?